# Table cell margin with Open XML

Tags: openxml

I would like to define cell margin at table level, just like here: [OOXML](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCellMargins.php)

with the following code:

```
var mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(
    new Body(
        new Paragraph(
            new Run(
                new Text("Create text in body - CreateWordprocessingDocument")))));

// Create an empty table.
Table table = new Table();

// Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
    new TableCellSpacing() { Width = "200", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
    new TableCellMargin(
        new TopMargin() { Width = "50", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
        new StartMargin() { Width = "200", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
        new BottomMargin() { Width = "0", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
        new EndMargin() { Width = "0", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa })
);
```

The cell spacing works, but the cell margin not. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **TableCellMarginDefault** in place of **TableCellMargin**.

- **TableCellMarginDefault** affects the table.
- **TableCellMargin** affects a single cell.

Your new code should look like this:

```
var mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(
    new Body(
        new Paragraph(
            new Run(
                new Text("Create text in body - CreateWordprocessingDocument")))));

// Create an empty table.
Table table = new Table();

// Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
    new TableCellSpacing() { Width = "200", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
    new TableCellMarginDefault(
        new TopMargin() { Width = "50", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
        new StartMargin() { Width = "200", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
        new BottomMargin() { Width = "0", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa },
        new EndMargin() { Width = "0", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa })
        );
```